# VS Code - Running dart console application ends in error and opens errors_patch.dart, how to stop this behavior?

Tags: dart, vscode-debugger

I decided to rewrite some of my js stuff with dart in VS Code.

When I launch the dart console app in debug mode, and there is a bug somewhere, an errors_patch.dart file opens up showing line 27. How can I stop this file from opening?

```
  @patch
  @pragma("vm:external-name", "Error_throwWithStackTrace")
  external static Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following.

1. Open [Debug and Run] View
2. Expand [BREAKPOINTS]
3. Uncheck [Uncaught Exceptions]